# Are there any playable races that are Fine?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, races, creature-size

I was watching a live party when it suddenly occured to me that a never saw a fine playable creature. But now that I'm thinking about it, I kinda fancy the idea to play Tinkerbell's male counterpart. I looked into faeries, but the pixies are about 30cm high. When I'm picturing a faerie, I imagining a small winged humanoid, maybe 10 cm high - only fine creature fits this size category. I'm not really into playing a winged garden gnome, fluff-wise.

The only fine creature that I found is the [puppeteer](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Puppeteer), from 3.5 edition. **I'm wondering if there is any race that can fill the following requirements:**

1. Less than 20cm - Fine or a small Diminutive creature (Fine: <15cm, Diminutive, <30cm)
2. Intelligent enough to be a playable race.
3. Winged would be a plus, but isn't necessary.

I don't know if puppeteer still exist in Pathfinder but the concept seems fun. I obviously won't be able to make a great warrior of a fine creature, but as support character could be quite interesting and challenging to play.

Comment: how about a silly one a fairy dragon, I know this is d&d but your GM might let you http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Faerie_dragon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a [list of all Paizo playable races](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races), and none of them go smaller than Small.  The shortest is the [halfling](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/halfling); the shortest halfling (according to the "random height" table) is 2ft 8in which is 81.3cm.

For [third-party races](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/3rd-party-races) there is the [kval](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/3rd-party-races/alluria-publishing/kval) which is size "tiny".  The shortest kval is 10 inches (25.4cm) tall.

For not too much money (3040gp total, I believe) you could pay a ninth-level wizard to cast a permanent *reduce person* spell on you, cutting your height in half again.

An eighth level druid can take the form of a Diminutive animal for eight hours, and can do this three times per day -- so essentially you could be a Diminutive animal forever if you wanted.  For example you could be a [thrush](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/thrush) which is around 20cm long.  If your intent is to play a dedicated spellcaster this is not a bad tactic (though the inability to speak might cause problems).

Answer (score 7):

There are none, and even [the race builder rules in the Advanced Race Guide](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/creating-new-races#TOC-Size-Quality) only cover building down to Tiny in size.

Comment: I checked the Crystalkeep index for 3.5e - there's no Fine races there, either.

Answer (score 2):

### There are no tiny-sized official playable races

While there are many creatures that fit your criteria, none of them were officially published as playable races. You would have to apply size-changing effects to a small-sized character in order to them become tiny-sized.

### Gathlain are small-sized fey playable characters

The [Gathlains](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/more-races/advanced-races-11-20-rp/gathlain-12-rp) were first introduced in *Advanced Race Guide*, and later republished in *Wilderness Adventures*. They are a playable *fey* race that is sized small, they can fly and have wings that look like they are made out of wood.

### Kitsune can become tiny foxes

Though they look nothing like fey for us westerns, a [Kitsune](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/uncommon-races/arg-kitsune/) with the *Superior Shapeshifter* alternate racial trait can polymorph into a *Tiny*-sized [fox](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/canines/fox/):

> Some talented kitsune take more naturally to shapeshifting than magic, and develop that gift. They gain **Fox Shape** as a bonus feat at 1st level, ignoring its prerequisites. This racial trait replaces kitsune magic

[Fox Shape](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/fox-shape/), in turn, says:

> Benefit: You can take the form of a fox whose appearance is static and cannot be changed each time you assume this form. Your bite attack’s damage is reduced to 1d3 points of damage on a hit, but you gain a +10 racial bonus on Disguise checks made to appear as a fox. Changing from kitsune to fox shape is a standard action. This ability otherwise functions as beast shape II, and your ability scores change accordingly.

### Third-party solutions

There is a third-party fey race called the [Fairy](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/extras/community-creations/black-flame-studios-lab/races/fairy/), which fits exactly into the visual and mechanics you want. It doesn't appear unbalanced in any way to me, as their strongest abilities are being able to fly at first level (already possible with 3 other official races), and having DR 5/Cold Iron.